# Chart disappears, when pressing the submit button

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I started learning the library `Chart.js` a few days ago, and I have a problem when I'm trying to create a graph, that depends by the user input.

I have 4 input boxes and a button, when I press the button it displays the graph, but only for few seconds.

This is the code I wrote for the graph:

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart;

  function display(a, b, c, d) {
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'data',
          data: [a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.5)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)',
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          ],

        }]
      },
      options: {}
    });
  }
</script>
```

and this is the code for the input:

```
<form>
  a: <input type="number" id="a"><br>
  b: <input type="number" id="b"><br>
  c: <input type="number" id="c"><br>
  d: <input type="number" id="d"><br>
  <button onclick="display(a,b,c,d)">display</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you check the console for any JS errors?

Comment: nothing in there

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, all you need to do is add an `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the page from actually submitting the form. All you really want to do is call the `display()` function.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kd4Lnwtj/5/

Comment: where am I adding an event.preventDefault()?

Comment: Try adding it right before your ‘myChart = new Chart...’

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

The default `type` attribute for any `<button>` within a `<form>` is "submit".

Try adding `type="button"` to the display button. That should stop it from submitting and just let your JavaScript run.

Something like:

`<button type="button" onclick="display(a,b,c,d)">display</button>`